# Ehcache:mirror group configuration

Tags: ehcache

I am trying to configure a mirror group for ehcache using terracotta..

My understanding is, the cache on all the members of the mirror group will be in sync.

Question is, how many members can be existing per mirror group?

Thanks,
-Venkat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically there is no limit on the number of mirrors in a group. But the recommendation is to have 1 extra server mirroring data for backup and bringing any extra mirrors as u need it. (For doing maintenance on one of the servers, for example)

Answer (score 0):

In one Terracotta mirror group (or stripe), there's one active server and one or more mirror servers (the hot standbys). These mirrors are for failover, so most use cases have one, sometimes two. However, note that there is sync overhead, so the more mirrors you add, the more drag on the active's performance as it tries to sync to them all. Practically speaking, one mirror is almost always enough.

There's a page about mirror-group architecture [here](http://terracotta.org/documentation/terracotta-server-array/server-arrays).